# pandas: append rows to another dataframe under the similar row based on column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have two dataframes as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
d1 ={'col1': ['I ate dinner','I ate dinner', 'the play was inetresting','the play was inetresting'],
 'col2': ['min', 'max', 'mid','min'],
 'col3': ['min', 'max', 'max','max']}

d2 ={'col1': ['I ate dinner',' the glass is shattered', 'the play was inetresting'],
     'col2': ['min', 'max', 'max'],
     'col3': ['max', 'min', 'mid']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I have created a column in df2 called 'exist' and added values (true, false) based on whether the sentences in df2.col1 exist in df1.col1:

```
common = df1.merge(df2,on=['col1'])
index_list = df2[(~df2.col1.isin(common.col1))].index.to_list()
df2['exist'] = ' '
df2.loc[index_list, 'exist'] = 'false'
df2.loc[df2["exist"] == " ",'exist'] = 'true'
```

what I would like to do now, is that if the value in the exist column == true, I would like to add that row under the similar row in df1. so the desired output should be:

```
output:
                       col1 col2 col3
0              I ate dinner  min  min
1              I ate dinner  max  max
2              I ate dinner  min  max
3  the play was inetresting  mid  max
4  the play was inetresting  min  max
5  the play was inetresting  max  mid
```

I guess I have to use np.where, but I am not sure how to formulate the append to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is filter `df2` values by `df1.col1` and append to `df1` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[(df2.col1.isin(df1.col1))]]).sort_values('col1', ignore_index=True)
print (df)
                       col1 col2 col3
0              I ate dinner  min  min
1              I ate dinner  max  max
2              I ate dinner  min  max
3  the play was inetresting  mid  max
4  the play was inetresting  min  max
5  the play was inetresting  max  mid
```

If need only common values in both DataFrames is possible filter by [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
common = np.intersect1d(df1['col1'], df2['col1'])

df = (pd.concat([df1[df1.col1.isin(common)],
                 df2[df2.col1.isin(common)]])
                     .sort_values('col1', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to add the matching row(s) and not necessarily rely on sorting.

```
df2b = df2.set_index('col1')

(df1
 .groupby('col1', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda d: pd.concat([d, df2b.loc[[d.name]].reset_index()]))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
                       col1 col2 col3
0              I ate dinner  min  min
1              I ate dinner  max  max
2              I ate dinner  min  max
3  the play was inetresting  mid  max
4  the play was inetresting  min  max
5  the play was inetresting  max  mid
```

Comment: ya, agree. If OP has small data and mainly need original order solution should be used in my opinion.